# Get function result instead of it body

Tags: javascript, jquery

Alert show the body of function instead of it result.

HTML:

```js
function calc () {
        var first = 1;
        var second = 2;
        var result = first + second;
        return result;
    }
$('#button').click(function(){alert(calc);});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="button" id="button" value="button">
```

Other example with `onclick` is working well:

```js
function calc () {
        var first = 1;
        var second = 2;
        var result = first + second;
        return result;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="button" id="button" value="button" onclick="alert(calc())">
```

Comment: For future reference: Always say what's wrong (what do you expect, what's happening instead).

Comment: There's a typo in your code.  The "working example" invokes the function: `alert(calc())`.  Whereas the "not working example" does not: `alert(calc)`.

Comment: The full content of your question must be **in** your question, not just linked. Links rot, making the question and its answers useless to people in the future, and people shouldn't have to go off-site to help you. Put a [mcve] **in** the question, using Stack Snippets (the `<>` toolbar button) to make it runnable (instead of hiding away details off-site). More: [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: `calc` just refers to the function. To **call** the function, use `calc()`: `$('#button').click(function(){alert(calc());});`. VTC as typo/no-repro.

Comment: Thank you guys. Will try ask more useful and correctly questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead **calc** of following line

```
$('#button').click(function(){alert(calc);})
```

Use **calc()** as shown below

```
 $('#button').click(function(){alert(calc());})
```

The difference between calc and calc() is

When you write `calc` that time you are passing the function as a Parameter instead of it's return value. This is useful when you are passing a function as a **Callback** to execute it later.

But When you write **calc()** that time you are executing means calling function.

Answer (score 1):

Update you code like this:

Call `calc()` not `calc`

```
function calc () {
        var first = 1;
        var second = 2;
        var result = first + second;
        return result;
    }
$('#button').click(function(){alert(calc());});
```